# google map sdk how to get current location in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a code like below  but "`CLLocation loc = mapView.MyLocation;`" assigne null to loc object, so i cannot take cuurent location.

How can get my current location in xamarin for ios with google map sdk for ios.

```
//and many other using
using Google.Maps;

public partial class MapNavigationController : UIViewController
{   

MapView mapView; 

   public override void LoadView ()
        {
            base.LoadView ();

            var camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera (latitude: 7.2935273, 
                longitude: 80.6387523, 
                zoom: 13);
            mapView = MapView.FromCamera (RectangleF.Empty, camera);

            mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;
            mapView.MapType = MapViewType.Hybrid;
            CLLocation loc = mapView.MyLocation;
                        Console.WriteLine("tapped at " + loc.Coordinate.Latitude + "," +loc.Coordinate.Longitude);
                 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Google Maps in iOS. 
But I don't think its possible to get you current location from the MapView.
You can maybe show it (by enabling an option (showOwnLocation or something similar)).
If you want to do it the right way you have to do it with the CLLocationManager from the iOS SDK. I don't have a sample available right now but if you google it you will find some.

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get that info from `CCLocationManager`, like so:

```
CameraPosition camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera(latitude: App.MyLatitude,
                                                                  longitude: App.MyLongitude,
                                                                  zoom:50);
            mapView = MapView.FromCamera(CGRect.Empty, camera);
            mapView.Settings.ScrollGestures = true;
            mapView.Settings.ZoomGestures = true;
            mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;
            mapView.MapType = MapViewType.Satellite;
            CLLocation loc = iPhoneLocationManager.Location;


            // My position
            var Marker = new Marker()
            {
                Title = App.PinTitle,
                Snippet = App.PinLabel,

                Position = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.Coordinate.Latitude, longitude: loc.Coordinate.Longitude),
                Map = mapView
            };
```